# Can you use Firebase Phone Auth without Play Integrity?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-app-check, google-play-integrity-api

We recently encounter an issue with the new Firebase Auth version. We are using it for years, unfortunately SafetyNet has been deprecated and we are now force to use other attestation one of which is the new Play Integrity. We never want to limit our app in Play Store, is there a way to continue using this particular Firebase product or this is the end of our freedom? Currently we are encountering this error during authentication.

> com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that Play Integrity checks, and reCAPTCHA checks were unsuccessful. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.

Comment: You said it yourself: "SafetyNet has been deprecated".  That means it doesn't have a supported lifetime beyond the deprecation period. I'd fully expect that it will not work at all after that.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson, is there any plan to support apps that is publish outside Play Store in the future to work with Play Integrity? Other Google product such as AdMob requires your app to be publish in either Play Store, Samsung, Amazon, etc. My point is if your app serves ads and they are publish on these stores then authentication with Firebase Phone Auth will no longer work for new users, kinda contradicting when used together with other Google product.

Comment: You're asking the wrong person.  Why don't you address Firebase directly using [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) or posting to [firebase-talk](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk)? Stack Overflow is run by a bunch of community volunteers that can't comment on the future of commercial products.